# percentage change between closest years

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a problem on creating a new variable `Growth`, which equals to percentage change in `Population` between closest years ending in “2” and “7”.

```
# dt
ID       Population      year
1                50      1995
1                60      1996
1                70      1997
1                80      1998
1                90      1999
1               100      2000
1               105      2001
1               110      2002
1               120      2003
1               130      2004
1               140      2005
1               150      2006
1               200      2007
1               300      2008

dt <- data.table::fread("ID       Population      year
1                50      1995
  1                60      1996
  1                70      1997
  1                80      1998
  1                90      1999
  1               100      2000
  1               105      2001
  1               110      2002
  1               120      2003
  1               130      2004
  1               140      2005
  1               150      2006
  1               200      2007
  1               300      2008", header = T)
```

Growth = Percentage change in Pop between closest years ending in “2” and “7”.    For example, in the year:
1996: (1997 Pop – 1992 Pop) / 1992 Pop
1997: (2002 Pop – 1997 Pop) / 1997 Pop
1998: (2002 Pop – 1997 Pop) / 1997 Pop
1999: (2002 Pop – 1997 Pop) / 1997 Pop
2000: (2002 Pop – 1997 Pop) / 1997 Pop
2001: (2002 Pop – 1997 Pop) / 1997 Pop
2002: (2007 Pop – 2002 Pop) / 2002 Pop
2003: (2007 Pop – 2002 Pop) / 2002 Pop
2004: (2007 Pop – 2002 Pop) / 2002 Pop
2005: (2007 Pop – 2002 Pop) / 2002 Pop
2006: (2007 Pop – 2002 Pop) / 2002 Pop
2007: (2012 Pop – 2007 Pop) / 2007 Pop
2008: (2012 Pop – 2007 Pop) / 2007 Pop

However, when I manipulate the `Growth`, I need to do this by column `ID`. Moreover, the range of year is from 1970 to 2018, really wide range. How can I do this in `data.table`?

Comment: In your example, 1992 Pop doesn't exist, so how would you calculate `Growth` for 1996? 2012 Pop also doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible `data.table` approach:

```
#calculate the 5-yearly percentage changes first by 
#i) first creating all combinations of ID and 5-yearly years
#2) then join with the original dataset 
#3) then leading the Population column and calculating Growth
pctChange <- dt[CJ(ID=ID, year=seq(1967, 2022, 5), unique=TRUE), 
    .(ID, year, Growth=(shift(Population, type="lead") - Population) / Population), 
    on=.(ID, year)]    

#then perform a rolling join (`roll=TRUE`; see ?data.table) and 
#then update the original dt with Growth by reference (i.e. `:=`)
dt[, Growth := pctChange[dt, Growth, on=.(ID, year), roll=TRUE]]
dt
```

output:

```
    ID Population year    Growth
 1:  1         50 1995        NA
 2:  1         60 1996        NA
 3:  1         70 1997 0.5714286
 4:  1         80 1998 0.5714286
 5:  1         90 1999 0.5714286
 6:  1        100 2000 0.5714286
 7:  1        105 2001 0.5714286
 8:  1        110 2002 0.8181818
 9:  1        120 2003 0.8181818
10:  1        130 2004 0.8181818
11:  1        140 2005 0.8181818
12:  1        150 2006 0.8181818
13:  1        200 2007        NA
14:  1        300 2008        NA
```

Point to note: rolling join appears not to work with update join

```
dt[pctChange, Growth := Growth, on=.(ID, year), roll=TRUE]
```

Comment: Great. How to do if I want to manipulate by `ID`? add `ID` inside `on = .(ID, year)`? Not sure

Comment: Thanks. What is the function `CJ` above?

Comment: it is a cross join function from `data.table`. You might want to check out `?data.table::CJ`

Answer (score 1):

Not a `data.table` solution, but here is how you might do it in the `tidyverse` which could give you some ideas. Basically calculate the year to compare to for each row using integer division `%/%`, and then join the table onto itself so we have the comparison value in each row. Then it is simple to calculate the growth using your formula.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- read_table("ID       Population      year
1                50      1995
1                60      1996
1                70      1997
1                80      1998
1                90      1999
1               100      2000
1               105      2001
1               110      2002
1               120      2003
1               130      2004
1               140      2005
1               150      2006
1               200      2007
1               300      2008")
dt %>%
  mutate(compare_year = 5 * year %/% 5 - 3) %>%
  left_join(dt, by = c("ID", "compare_year" = "year")) %>%
  mutate(growth = (Population.x - Population.y) / Population.y)
#> # A tibble: 14 x 6
#>       ID Population.x  year compare_year Population.y growth
#>    <int>        <int> <int>        <dbl>        <int>  <dbl>
#>  1     1           50  1995         1992           NA NA    
#>  2     1           60  1996         1992           NA NA    
#>  3     1           70  1997         1992           NA NA    
#>  4     1           80  1998         1992           NA NA    
#>  5     1           90  1999         1992           NA NA    
#>  6     1          100  2000         1997           70  0.429
#>  7     1          105  2001         1997           70  0.5  
#>  8     1          110  2002         1997           70  0.571
#>  9     1          120  2003         1997           70  0.714
#> 10     1          130  2004         1997           70  0.857
#> 11     1          140  2005         2002          110  0.273
#> 12     1          150  2006         2002          110  0.364
#> 13     1          200  2007         2002          110  0.818
#> 14     1          300  2008         2002          110  1.73
```

Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @calum_you, but using nearest 5yr growth, as requested in OP.

**Sample data**

```
dt <- data.table::fread("ID       Population      year
1                50      1995
  1                60      1996
  1                70      1997
  1                80      1998
  1                90      1999
  1               100      2000
  1               105      2001
  1               110      2002
  1               120      2003
  1               130      2004
  1               140      2005
  1               150      2006
  1               200      2007
  1               300      2008", header = T) %>%
  as_data_frame()
```

**1) 5yr growth rates table**

```
dt_5yr <- dt %>% 
  filter(year %% 10 %in% c(2,7)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%   # I assume there will be more IDs in full data
  mutate(growth_5yr = Population / lag(Population) - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**2) Join original table to 5yr growth rates**

```
dt %>%
  mutate(join_yr = year + 5 - (year + 3) %% 5) %>%
  left_join(dt_5yr %>% select(join_yr = year, growth_5yr))
```

**Output**

```
   ID Population year join_yr growth_5yr
1   1         50 1995    1997         NA
2   1         60 1996    1997         NA
3   1         70 1997    2002  0.5714286
4   1         80 1998    2002  0.5714286
5   1         90 1999    2002  0.5714286
6   1        100 2000    2002  0.5714286
7   1        105 2001    2002  0.5714286
8   1        110 2002    2007  0.8181818
9   1        120 2003    2007  0.8181818
10  1        130 2004    2007  0.8181818
11  1        140 2005    2007  0.8181818
12  1        150 2006    2007  0.8181818
13  1        200 2007    2012         NA
14  1        300 2008    2012         NA
```